# Give an example of a homeomorphism of a compact metric space that has a dense orbit but no dense semiorbit.

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I am at a loss in trying to find such a function. I know it must only be bijective and continuous to be a homeomorphism since it is a compact metric space. However, every function I've tried to construct is either not continuous, or has dense semi orbits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take 1-point compactification X of the set of integers and let f act on X by addition of 1 to integers and fixing infinity. Clearly, X is metrizable.

Comment: Thank you, but how do we know it is metrizable?

Comment: It embeds in the circle.